# NullPointerException in Android Developement

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

`at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.findPdf(MainActivity.java:63)
at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.findPdf(MainActivity.java:67)
at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.findPdf(MainActivity.java:67)
at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.displayPdf(MainActivity.java:84)
at com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity$1.onPermissionGranted(MainActivity.java:44)

i am tring to build PdfReader app and in ArrayList findpdf(); method i had got some exceptions and it leads to bugs in app so its gone be crahshed `

```
package com.example.pdfreader;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPdfSelectListner{

    private MainAdapter adapter;
    private List<File> pdfList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        runtimePermission();

    }


    private void runtimePermission(){
        Dexter.withContext(MainActivity.this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                       displayPdf();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Requried", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }

    public ArrayList<File> findPdf (File file)
    {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<> ();
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for (File singleFile :files)
            {
                if (singleFile.isDirectory () && !singleFile.isHidden())
                {
                    arrayList.addAll(findPdf(singleFile));
                }
                else{
                    if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                        arrayList.add(singleFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        return  arrayList;
    }

    public void displayPdf()
    {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        pdfList = new ArrayList<> ();
        pdfList.addAll(findPdf (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
        adapter = new MainAdapter(this, pdfList,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPdfSelected(File file) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PdfActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("paht",file.getAbsolutePath()));

    }
}


Here, is the all code of the MainActivity.java and although on calling the displayPdf(); method in runtimePermission(); is ok or shall we need to modify this functions.
```

Comment: Or we need to modify the displayPdf(); method ??? as like this crashes:          com.example.pdfreader.MainActivity.displayPdf(MainActivity.java:84) at

Comment: fill is null in findPdf (File file) method call.

Comment: where @AbdullahJaved bhi

Comment: if (singleFile==null){
                    findPdf(null);

                }                                        //   added this condition in for loop even but does'nt work also

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException: files must not be null" That's the main problem in findPdf method. You need to perform null check before for loop.

Comment: can you give the code for that as like i had answer here but it won't work

Comment: Do you want to get all pdf files list from external storage?

Comment: yes sir all pdf

Comment: is we need to update displayPdf(); ??  is this able to display all exteranl pdf??

Comment: can you try to modifty my code methods like findpdf(); and display(); coz your 1st solution won't work till as i used the getAllPdf(); method but it gets problem in displayPdf();

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method to get all pdf files in external directory. Customize it for your usage.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllPdf() {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"application/pdf"};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = requireActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        ArrayList<String> pdfFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));

                pdfFiles.add(fileName + " (" + filePath + ")");
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return pdfFiles;
    }
```

Comment: what is requireActivity() of the cursor???

Comment: sir i can't understood this function problem it had requireActivity(),cursor and pdfFiles content which is trouble to understand can you please figure out with my findPdf method and give proper result

Comment: i had used this but it won't work well till but the app doesn't gone in crashed

Comment: hello???????? plz try to figure out it

Comment: can you try to modifty my code methods like findpdf(); and display(); coz your 1st solution won't work till as i used the getAllPdf(); method but it gets problem in displayPdf();

Comment: https://github.com/sachinbhujbal/Pdf-Reader

Comment: can you plz look into this git repo of  mainActivity.java here is everything i think you can solve it the pdf won't be display and i am quite enough sure that even can't be fetch from external storage

Comment: https://github.com/AbdullahJaved-dev/Pdf-Reader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pdfreader/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<File> findPdf(File file) {
    ArrayList<File> pdfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    pdfFiles.addAll(findPdf(f));
                } else if (f.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    pdfFiles.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e("findPdf", "NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return pdfFiles;
}

Even I tried this to catch nullpointerexception but it won't work again but now the app not gone be crashed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllPdf() {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"application/pdf"};
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = requireActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        ArrayList<String> pdfFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));

                pdfFiles.add(fileName + " (" + filePath + ")");
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return pdfFiles;
    }

I Had used that getAllPdf(); method but how to extract the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); through displayPdf(); using arrayList??

here is the displayPdf(); method

 public void displayPdf()
    {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        pdfList = new ArrayList<> ();

        // this line give me error while adding Environment through arraylist 

pdfList=getAllPdf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        adapter = new MainAdapter(this, pdfList,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).